# Getline doesn't work for some reason

Tags: c++, getline, stringstream

map - is a file that I opened.
line - string

The upper part works, but the lower part does not.

```
    getline(map, line);
    getline(ssvalues, values, '|'); // Gets the name of the tileset file
    tileset.loadFromFile(values.c_str());
    getline(ssvalues, values, ' '); // Gets the size of the tile
    tileSize = atoi(values.c_str());

    getline(map, line); // Reads the next line.
    ssvalues.str(line);

    values = "";

    // FROM HERE IT DOESNT WORK, 'values' always empty, why--
    getline(ssvalues, values, '|'); // Get the X size of map
    std::cout<<values;
    mapSize.x = atoi(values.c_str());
    getline(ssvalues, values, ' '); // Get the Y size of map
    mapSize.y = atoi(values.c_str());
    std::cout<<values;
```

The content of the file that I'm reading is:

```
tileset.png|32
1200|1200
```

Comment: `getline` absolutely does work. You did something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
ssvalues.str(line);
```

Here you reset the "contents" of the stringstream's buffer, but you didn't clear its error flags. Since it already hit EOF, this flag is still set and future `getline` calls will fail.

You should add error checking into your code for all these input operations, and write the following instead of the above:

```
ssvalues.clear();
ssvalues.str(line);
```